# Accessing structure members using base address

Tags: c, pointers

Can you please help explain why following program correctly prints the values of all the structure members?

```
struct st
{
  int i;
  char c1;
  int j;
  char c2;
};

int main()
{
  struct st a = {5, 'i', 11, 'H'};
  struct st * pa = &a;

  int first;
  char second;
  int third;
  char fourth;

  first = *((int*)pa);
  second = *((char*)pa + 4); /* offset = 4 bytes = sizeof(int) */
  third = *((int*)pa + 2); /* why (pa + 2) here? */
  fourth = *((char*)pa + 12); /* why (pa + 12) here? */
  printf ("first = %d, second = %c, third = %d, fourth = %c\n", first, second, third, fourth);
  return 0;
}
```

Output: first = 5, second = i, third = 11, fourth = H

How can I make above program generalized?

Comment: Search for "C struct padding alignment". (Your code is not portable btw.)

Comment: Note the casting and pointer arithmetic. `(char*)pa + 4` is adding the size of 4 chars. `(int*)pa + 2` is adding the size of 2 ints.

Answer (score 1):

That's because of the padding bytes added to the structure. Three padded bytes will be added after `char second;`, this is because the `char` is followed by an `int` (member with larger alignment) so padding bytes will be inserted to make the alignment multiple of the alignment of larger member.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of `structure` padding.

After padding your `structure` will look like below.

```
struct st
{
  int i;
  char c1;
  char padding[3]; // for alignment of j.
  int j;
  char c2; 
  char padding[3]; // for alignment of structure.
};
```

Hence

```
first = *((int*)pa);
  second = *((char*)pa + 4); /* offset = 4 bytes = sizeof(int) */
  third = *((int*)pa + 2); /* offset = 8 bytes(pointer arithmetic) to point to int j*/
  fourth = *((char*)pa + 12); /* offset = 12 bytes to point to char c2*/
```

> For more info on structure padding read
>   [Data_structure_alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make above program generalized?

The only way to make it work reliably is by not guessing at the offset. Use the standard [offsetof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/offsetof) macro, and always do the pointer arithmetic with a character pointer:

```
first = *(int*)((char*)pa + offsetof(struct st, i));
```

You don't have to name the field at the point you do the access, but you should definitely use the macro to compute the offest if you intend to pass it into your function.

Comment: Why not use something else then the member `i` in your example? `i` as being the 1st member could very well "*reliably*" be accessed by doing `first = *(int*)pa;`

Comment: @alk - I just wanted to concisely show how to obtain the correct offset for any member, and how to use the offset correctly. It's also reliable to say real code will do for instance `pa->j` instead of mucking with offsets and casts.

Answer (score 0):

As in another answers - `padding`.

But some compilers allow you to pack your structures removing (in most cases) the padding.

gcc:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) st
{
....
}
```

The code which access the packed structs may be less efficient and longer.

Answer (score -1):

When creating a struct, all variables occupy the same amount of space (32 bits), the remaining unused bits are padding. So even if you define a `char` in the struct, this will occupy 4 bytes.
This is due to the fact that your processor addresses data at 32 bits, even if afterwards less bits are used. The memory on the other side stores 1 byte for each address, but when data is fetched by the CPU, data will be adapted to the bus architecture (that depends on the processor).

Also note that the offset depends on the pointer you are using. a `char*` in this case will increase by 1, while a `int*` by 4.

This also means that the code is not portable, since, for example, `int` may not be defined of the same size on different architectures.

Comment: "*This also means that the code is not portable*" this is not was is commonly understood as being "*not portable*". Did not DV, BTW.